# Why can't I use click() with my web telegram Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a simple Chrome extension that will work with [web telegram](https://web.telegram.org) using JavaScript.

The problem is in using the `click()` function (also I tried to use `submit()` to the form but had the same result). I cannot click any buttons there and can`t understand why.

For example, I want to choose a chat, so use this code. I use `onmouseover` event just for easy testing click(). And I also tried to use the trigger function (jQuery) and had the same result - nothing happened.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.querySelector('.im_panel_peer_photo').onmouseover = handler;
  function handler(e) {
    let contactLis = document.querySelectorAll('.im_dialog_wrap')
    console.log(contactLis[3]) // got correct obj
    contactLis[3].click()
  };
};
```

I also noticed in the console some messages like "API call account.updateStatus" after I choose one of the contacts. So maybe I need to use requests or something.

By the way, I tried to use the same code on another website and click function works perfectly.

UPD I found out that web telegram is written using Angular. That's why it is difficult to make such interactions.

Comment: Probably, some objects support click function, but not the main that I need(contacts and send). I think the problem is that some elements in web telegram are created by appendChild using js or Angular. This is just an assumption, I don’t know if this could be the reason.

Comment: Where is this code located?  Better yet, could you show your background, popup.js, popup, html, etc.  This happened with me, and it has to do with [ContentSecurityPolicy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy).  I was able to resolve it but we would like to know what page the above code runs in...